# Is it possible to change content of a file residing on other server using HTTP 1.1 features?

Tags: security, apache-http-server, http, webserver

Let's say we have a file on server which have all permissions `777`. Is it possible to make a script, situated on other server than the file to modify. The script uses HTTP 1.1 protocol features only to modify  the file. Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes, it is possible. HTTP 1.1 has the `PUT` and `PATCH` write commands as well as a `DELETE` command. However, they are not implemented on most web servers. You need to tell Apache to accept the `PUT`/`PATCH`/`DELETE` commands and have a specific program or script handle those commands to do the writing and deleting.

Luckily, [this W3C page](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/Put.html) lists 2 web servers ([Jigsaw](http://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/) is the only one still maintained) that support `PUT` by default plus an easy way to set up Apache to also support it.